# ApiRTC issue with ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework

ApiRTC
we have a consultation app and below are the issues we are facing

-iPhone to android

- android to android
  When the call is ended during the running session, and when the caller tries to call again Application hanged and the screen turned to black when trying to call again the caller side is giving a ringing tone but the callee is not receiving the call

The caller had to close the application and reopen it again then the call will go through

- On android 10
  When the call is ended during the running session, and when the caller tries to call again Application hanged and Chat is erased.

Answer (score 1):

There were some improvements made recently around webrtc support by different OS web-browsers you are mentioning. Theses shall fix the issues you are describing.

Also the most recent versions of Ionic, with usage of capacitor, have fixed a few issues we were facing.

We have a blog post on the subject (https://apirtc.com/building-a-webrtc-mobile-app-with-ionic/) that does not show issues you are mentioning, please give it a try !